# SemiCompRisks package and encourage to one error

Tags: machine-learning, formula, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

> `Blockquote`

**strong text**> - ```

> library(Formula)
>
> library(SemiCompRisks)
>
> library(haven)
>
> CRC_Final_04 <- read_sav("X0_CRC_Final_04.sav")
>
> CRC_Final_04 <- read_sav("C:/Users/Uaer/Downloads/X0_CRC_Final_04.sav")
>
> scrdata <- CRC_Final_04
>
> names (scrdata)

> - #### **`form <- Formula(time_recurrence + delta_recurrence | time_survival + delta_survival ~ age_cat |age_cat)
>
>   **Error in is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20 :
>   'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`****

hi all

I encourage this error when I used SemiCompRisks and Formula packages.

what is your idea for correcting this?